Are Banno Plugin Framework UI/UX Design Guidelines just suggestions?
We are beginning to work on an external application and looking around it seems the Design System components are not available to a third party fintech and the suggestion in the plugin docs is to use themes to make it appear seamless.
How far is that enforced? If we open up our external application, other than colors, can our external application look nothing like Banno or does Jack Henry prefer that the external application look and feel as if it's part of the Banno experience?
I've looked through documentation for plugins, external applications and the Design System docs.

There is no specific enforcement from Jack Henry on the topic of making a plugin card fit seamlessly into the user's Dashboard experience.

This means that, hypothetically, if you built a plugin card that used a garish color scheme and which had a dreadful user interface, there's nothing stopping you from moving forward.

With that being said, account holders expect that the UI for their digital banking experience should feel like it belongs to the branding for that financial institution.

While this is not something enforced by Jack Henry itself, in practice it is enforced by each financial institution (for their own institution).

We have the Designing and Developing Plugins guide to help with building plugins that will look great and feel great too.
